# Openmp C Compilation Error

Tags: c, openmp

I am new to openmp and c. I am trying to compile a basic program. I am having some issues. Can someone help guide me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
#include <omp.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

#pragma omp parallel for private(i, a) num_threads(3)  
for (i=0; i<5; i++) 
  {
    a[i] = i + 1; 
    printf(“Thread %d has a value of a = %d for i = %d\n”, 
              omp_get_thread_num(), a[i], i); 
  } /*end of parallel for */ 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum, getting the actual error message would help...

Just in case, did you declare `a` and `i` somewhere? Did you enable OpenMP support for your compiler?

I did add these in the code and compiled it myself. Here is what it gives then:

```
#include <omp.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a[5], i;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, a) num_threads(3)  
for (i=0; i<5; i++) 
  {
    a[i] = i + 1; 
    printf("Thread %d has a value of a = %d for i = %d\n", 
              omp_get_thread_num(), a[i], i); 
  } /*end of parallel for */ 

}
```

And the result is

```
$ gcc -fopenmp sample_omp.c 
$ ./a.out 
Thread 2 has a value of a = 5 for i = 4
Thread 1 has a value of a = 3 for i = 2
Thread 1 has a value of a = 4 for i = 3
Thread 0 has a value of a = 1 for i = 0
Thread 0 has a value of a = 2 for i = 1
```

Comment: I am not clear on what is a and i is in this sample code. I haven't declared it yet. I haven't enabled support yet.